# laravel 5.4 queue:work --once but limit to 20 jobs

Tags: php, laravel, cron, queue, schedule

I'm trying to work an activation-email queue using laravel schedule,

I know i should run the the worker deamon using supervisor,

- But i can't install it on the server,
  i need to use only schedule(witch using cronjob every minute).

---

i added the cronjob using "crontab -e" for the schedule and it's running every minute like it should.

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php-5.6 [project dir]/artisan schedule:run > '/dev/null' 2>&1
```

And on the schedule function in app/console/kernal.php i added ,

```
$schedule->command('queue:work --queue=activation-email --timeout=30 --once')->withoutOverlapping()->everyMinute();
```

And it's working, but it's no good since it can handle only **one mail per minute**, and i want it to run every minute and handle at least 20-30 emails per minute...

---

The user must not wait more the 1min for he's activation email, and if multiple users register in the same period of time the users will wait for too long! witch is very bad...

so instead --once it's need to run - do max of 10 jobs and die every minute.

how can i execute queues without running a daemon process in the 
background all the time?

i searched the web for hours and couldn't find a solution...

---

thanks allot,

your help is appreciated!!

EDIT:

I tried doing this:

```
        for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
        $schedule->command('queue:work --queue=activation-email --timeout=30 --once')->withoutOverlapping();
    }
```

but it's feel soooo wrong.... to open 10 deamons evey minutes, instead of one to do 10 jobs... but i'ts working pretty well (and fast), but my guess it's killing the CPU.. any better solution for this? thanks...

Comment: maby a way to run it for 5min and gracefully killing it and restarting it again every 5 min? anyone?